# Searching for a string in DataGridView and keeping visible only the result

Tags: powershell, search, foreach, datagridview, match

I have a search text box in a form that uses `-match`.
A `Write-Host` shows a positive result when the search matches, but the DataGridView is hidden everything.

I have tried 2 solutions but without success; both returns "MATCH!!!" but all rows become invisible, which is unexpected:

1st approach:

```
foreach ($row in $DataGridView1.Rows) {
    foreach ($cell in $row.Cells) {
        if ($cell.Value.ToString() -match ($searchTextBox.Text)) {
            $DataGridView1.Rows[$row.Index].Visible = $true
            Write-Host "MATCH!!!"
        } else {
            $DataGridView1.Rows[$row.Index].Visible = $false
        }
    }
}
```

2nd approach:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $DataGridView1.RowCount; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j -lt $DataGridView1.ColumnCount; $j++) {
        $CurrentCell = $DataGridView1.Rows[$i].Cells[$j]
        if ($CurrentCell.Value.ToString() -match ($searchTextBox.Text)) {
            $DataGridView1.Rows[$i].Visible = $true
            Write-Host "MATCH!!!"
        } else {
            $DataGridView1.Rows[$i].Visible = $false
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like both codes are doing `$DataGridView1.Rows[$i].Visible = $false` every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner loops of both of your approaches define the visibility of the row for each cell individually. Unless the *last* cell in a row produces a match the row will end up hidden, even if a match was found in another cell before.

What you actually want is set the row visible if a match was found in any of the cells in a row, so you need to remember if a match was already found in the current row, and set the visibility *after* processing *all* cells of the row.

Change the inner loop to something like this:

```
$found = $false
foreach ($cell in $row.Cells) {
    if ($cell.Value.ToString() -match ($searchTextBox.Text)) {
        $found = $true
        Write-Host "MATCH!!!"
        break
    }
}
$DataGridView1.Rows[$row.Index].Visible = $found
```

and it should do what you want.

The additional `break` in the condition is a performance optimization. Once a match is found there is no need to test the remaining cells of the row, so you can skip the rest of the loop, set the visibility, and move to the next row.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ansgar. The logic behind your solution is perfect! I see now exactly what was the problem.